# Getting time using time picker and show it using Toast, code doesn't work

Tags: android, toast, timepicker

I was trying a simple code which shows time selected using Toast and time picker but nothing happens and there was no errors, the same also happens in date picker.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TimePicker tP;

public  void clickMe(View V){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Time Selected: " + (tP.getCurrentHour()) + ":" + tP.getCurrentMinute(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tP = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
}
```

I've only made a time picker in the layout and an `onclick:clickMe`.

Note: This was supposed to work because I've taken this code from an instructor.

**Edit:**

Here is layout:

```
<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="clickMe" />
```

**Edit 2**

Sorry, maybe i should have elaborated my question:

Why isn't my code not working?

for now i don't need the solution i just want the reason why this didn't work?

thanks.

Comment: Have you connected the click event of the time picker with this activity? Otherwise how does this method know to be called? Can you show us you layout xml file?

Comment: layout in edit, isn't it connected this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT 2:*** Btw make sure you press part that shows selected time, and the toast will pop up

***EDIT***
  add following line into XML if you want it to be clickable:

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

=======================================================================
***Alternative solution:*** 
Try adding OnClickListener in onCreate method, just after you call findViewById, and remove onClick attribute from the layout..

```
    tm = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepciker_id);
    tm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Time Selected: " + (tP.getCurrentHour()) + ":" + tP.getCurrentMinute(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setOnTimeChangedListener instead of onClick as follows:

```
 tP = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

 tP.setOnTimeChangedListener( new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " "+ String.valueOf(minute),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

        setTime(timePicker, hour, minute);

    }
}
```

and call this as

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```